# img not visible .. but it is there

Tags: html, image, firefox

something confusing.. I have a img-tag

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/1452630193_9305-normal.jpg" class="fqfqpowzxfpdkrchufzi">
```

But the image is not visible in the browser (FF 48.0.2).. the inspector says "could not load file".. but when I copy the path and paste it in the url of the browser, the image is definetly there.

also on my older version of FF, the image shows up correctly.

did I miss something important? why is the image not showing up?

Comment: Is this the exact img path? Then your problem is, that the corresponding web server doesn't deliver an img, but a html-page, which cannot be rendered when included in an img tag.

Comment: @Sankar Raj 
the css is minified.. the class is inserted by the browser itself..maybe I show the site.. it is this url  http://djeasy.net/gallery/ .. in chrome and in older FF everything is fine.. i don't understand it

Comment: @Kaiido .. i look at this, but I don't understand why the images are not there :/ .. second, no there is no https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all of the images are located in the "ad_min" directory, I think you have an adblocker that has picked up the "ad" in the URL and blocked the image from loading.

My chrome dev tools has said that the image has been blocked from loading by the client, which is why I am suspicious.

I disabled my adblock, and surely enough, the images did load like they were meant to

Comment: DUDE !!!!  :D ..  thank you very much! .. you rock! :) .. i searched for a week now.. and then this :D .. thanks a lot!

Comment: @crunchy linked their site "http://djeasy.net/gallery/" in a comment beneath their answer, which I visited

Comment: ah my bad, missed this link